# Compiling VAX Fortran on OSX?

Tags: macos, compilation, fortran, fortran77

I have some old fortran77 code that I need to run that's way too long to rewrite. It was written for the old Lahey LF90 compiler, using the vax option. Is there a free compiler out there I can use which will compile with the same options?

I was using gfortran as is and it was giving me nonsense. I read somewhere that g77 has an option for it (-fvxt?) but I can't seem to find any way to actually install g77.

edit for clarity: It was compiling properly, but when the program was run the calculations were giving me nonsense. Namely, extremely large negative mass in addition to other problems.

Comment: To install g77 you'll need to download and build a gcc 3.x release which are now over 10 years old.  If you want help getting your code to compile with a modern compiler you'll need to include the compiler output you consider "nonsense" so we have a clue what is going on.  Also include any relevant command you ran to compile the code.

Comment: You might also try the intel Fortran compiler `ifort`.  It supports a lot of the extensions that the VAX compiler supported.

Comment: So, it's this older modeling program, and it's not that it doesn't compile or outputs an error, it's just that the values it gives for certain things are obviously wrong (like calculating large negative mass or 0 for things that obviously shouldn't be zero). The program works fine when I use the pre-compiled .exe file, but I'd like to actually be able to make changes to the program which requires recompiling.

I will try ifort, thank you! I will also look into installing an older version of gcc.

Comment: Its a fair bet the old code is assuming uninitialzed variables to be zero or something similar. Turn on full checks and warnings and track down the actual issue.

Comment: Hmm, that's very possible. I do get some warnings when I compile, usually about memory management and such, but I can try it with better checks. However, it is around ~25,000 lines of code across ~10 files, so that might end up being more trouble than it's worth. Although if I can't get another compiler to work, then I guess I'll have to.